# Is there a way to toggle a secure lock screen without having the feature built into a custom ROM?

Tags: lock-screens, custom-roms, 5.1-lollipop, nexus, quick-settings

Benzo Rom for the Nexus 6 running 5.1.1 Lollipop allows the ability to toggle a secure lock screen from the quick settings in the notification drawer. For example, from the launcher, I can pull down the notification drawer to access the quick settings panel and tap the lock screen option and it will automatically engage the lock screen even if there was a password/pattern/gesture/pin, etc. previously setup. If I tap it again, it will remove the secure lock screen.

My concern is that this feature was built into the custom ROM itself and I don't know an alternate solution to this. Is there any solution to achieve this?

**Edit #1**

I was hoping for a solution that was not related to Tasker or Secure Settings. Something that's more clean and integrated.

Answer (score -1):

#### I'm not too familar with doing stuff like this, but I guess this will help!

Well, I'm pretty sure the app called [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) is able to do it if the Android version is between 4.x.x and 6.x.x, not sure if [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) can do it?

I do personally recommend [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) if you want an app that is able to do a lot on your phone, even without ROOT it can do amazing stuff. Else I would recommend to give [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) a try, I'm not that familar with it and can't tell that much about it.

**Tasker**

- Cost's 3 USD!
- Create and sell your own apps!
- I don't know what it can't do! I'm not kidding!

**Automate**

- It's free to download and ad-free!
- Easy-to-use drag-n-drop design!
- Built-in community to download other user's uploaded automation tasks!

**Both**

- Automating what ever you want, just like you want!
- Use ROOT functions like executing shell commands or rebooting you phone!

*Sorry for my bad english if it's not good enough! At least, I tried my best!*

*EDIT:* I'm not able to tell you that any app can help you with a Nexus 6 because I do only have a Galaxy S7 Edge that is working and a Galaxy S5 without a working display.

Comment: Both of thoose apps can trigger an action automatically e.g. if you are connected to a specified Wi-Fi network, in a specified location with a specified radius, when the time hit a specified time or is between 2 times you've choosen, and so on. Well, I'm actually using Tasker as a daily-use app because fingerprint on my modded phone doesn't allways work while the screen is off, but because of Tasker, I have created a super easy fix for it :P

Comment: Hi! Can you  provide the answer to the question? Tasker and Automation is good, but what do I do with them with respect to the question? Thanks!

Comment: @Firelord How to use thoose apps depends on what you are going to do with them, how you would like to do it and witch app. If you want to use Automate, it's easy to find examples to learn how the app works, if you want to use Tasker you will need to search and test untill you find a solution on how to use it. The question where just how to disable/enable the lock screen, and I know Tasker is able to do it, but the question got edited because he/she didn't want to use Tasker. (sorry for my bad english and bad explain)